# Can i open a new shell window or tab with node.js

Tags: node.js, shelljs

When i use `shelljs`, How can i execute script by opening another shell window or tab ?

I need to start api server and build app both. like

`var shell = require('shelljs');
...
shell.exec('node server.js');
shell.exec('npm run build')`

Comment: You want to run both `node server.js` and `npm run build` at the same time?

Comment: yeah. I want to keep the server running in the background and build my app at the same time.  Do you have a good idea?